# Cannot remove any component / connection in Talend

Tags: etl, talend

I installed Talend last month, and no component can be deleted, as shown below:
[image]

No job is running, and this happens to all jobs. I cannot do modification at all.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you use SVN?

Comment: On this pic, you are trying to delete the name of the connection, not the connection itself.

Answer (score 2):

**Case**

The context menu in Talend is very inconsistent. By no means all actions are available there all the time. You also need to know specific menus or key commands.

**Solution**

*Row iterators*

For this case there are two approaches:

1. Click `row1`, then hit `Del` on your keyboard
2. Re-route the little black dot at the `I` with drag and drop to another components input and you are set.

*Components*

The same here, just click on it and hit `Del`.

*NOTE:* If you have further issues with the jobs, please open specific questions to those issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a component / row(connecting line between components) , please select the component/row and click on the delete button on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to **edit** any of the jobs, then it points to an access related issue.

1. If you are using svn to save the jobs, it could be an svn access issue.
2. If you are using remote connection in an enterprise version, it could be that you no longer have access to the specific project